# Unsupported Media Type - 415 error in POST request in Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am trying out Graph Explorer. I am able to get my profile from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`.

But when I try to create a device using the Graph Explorer, it is returning `Unsupported Media Type - 415` response.

My request and response are:

**Request**

POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices`

Request headers
`Content-type: application/json`

Request body

```
{
    "accountEnabled": false,
    "alternativeSecurityIds": [
        {
            "type": 3,
            "key": "base64Y3YxN2E1MWFlYw=="
        }
    ],
    "deviceId": "4c299165-6e8f-4b45-a5ba-c5d250a707ff",
    "displayName": "Test device",
    "operatingSystem": "linux",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "1"
}
```

I have given the consent for all permissions under `Modify permissions` section.

**Response**

`Unsupported Media Type - 415 - 1168ms`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "The specified content type 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata, application/json' contains either no media type or more than one media type, which is not allowed. You must specify exactly one media type as the content type.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "11235ffc-1fb3-4324-a832-2c92274e98bf",
            "date": "2020-04-06T16:55:17"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

value of `deviceId` in the request data

Comment: `deviceId` should be a GUID/UUID. I doubt that would cause a `415` but it will fail.

Comment: I used the data given in the example in the create device [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-post-devices?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

"DeviceId" AND "Key" that you are passing in Request body should be Unique identifier. Change you sample Device-Id & Key and try again. It worked for me. and you also increased the length of device id by appending 1 at end.

Documentation for accountEnabled [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Comment: I tried with `accountEnabled: true`, again its showing the same error. Is there anything else you I can do to get it run.

Comment: @naseem Are you using personal Microsoft account here ? MSA accounts are not supported in this scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-post-devices?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: I am not using personal account. Clearly I am able to send get device list request successfully. For which am getting a `200 OK` response with `"value": []`.

Comment: @naseem "DeviceId" AND "Key" that you are passing in Request body should be Unique identifier. Change you sample Device-Id & Key and try again. It worked for me. and you also increased the length of device id by appending 1 at end.

Comment: but does it have to do anything with the type of the media? 
PS: I tried changing that too..

Comment: @naseem Could you try with "type" : 2 ? and let me know what error you get .

Comment: I am getting the same error. 
Unsupported Media Type - 415 - 634m

Comment: Hi @naseem, I was not able to reproduce your issue. I am also able to create the device.